# Reporting Solution for Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, report

im in very beginning stages of designing a system to be run on google app engine.  my problem are reports.  so far i have about 75 reports that need done and by the time im finished with the design im guessing 200 isn't going to be out of line.  i wanted to use jasper but apparently GAE doesn't support java.awt which breaks jasper

are there any other report packages out there that can give me the front end development power of jasper or crystal and still run on GAE with this schemaless data model?

Answer (score 1):

We have been using pyJasper (https://github.com/hudora/pyJasper)
for about five years now with several hundred documents daily.
To generate the report, you send the report and the content to the jasper server via a http interface. The jasper server is a dedicated Amazon EC2 instance.

If you use Python, have a look at a different client:
https://github.com/hudora/huTools/blob/master/huTools/pyjasper.py

If you need help, don't hesitate to ask!